# Calling two Promises within each other in Node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

So I have a MySQL query that I need to call within another MySQL query in the following format:

```
var sql = "some sql code";

    const queryResult = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      connection.query(sql, (err, rows, fields) => {

        // do some stuff here

        var secondSql = "Another sql command";

        const queryTwo = await new Promise((resolve) => {
          connection.query(secondSql, (err, rows, fields) => {

            // do some more stuff
            resolve(something);

        )});

         resovle(something);
      }
  )});
```

But, when I try to run this, I keep getting the error:

```
"errorMessage": "await is only valid in async function",
"errorType": "SyntaxError",
```

I know this has something to do with the "await new Promise((resolve) => {" not being async, but how do I fix this to actually run? I previously would just insert an async function outside of this code and call it where I have the second SQL query, but that does not work in AWS Lambdas for some reason.

Could someone please show me another way of doing this?

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You can only use the `await` keyword inside a function that has the `async` keyword.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find a loophole in the problem of dealing with async code. There is no loop hole. Either way you end up with a promise. It seems like it would be easier in this case to forget promises and just do the work in the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

In order for await to work, it has to be called from inside an async function. Try this:

```
var sql = "some sql code";

const queryResult = await new Promise((resolve) => {
  connection.query(sql, async (err, rows, fields) => {

    // do some stuff here

    var secondSql = "Another sql command";

    const queryTwo = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      connection.query(secondSql, (err, rows, fields) => {

        // do some more stuff
        resolve(something);

    )});

     resolve(something);
  }
)});
```

Comment: Where's the `async` for the first `await` at `queryResult = await new Promise`?

Comment: This will not work. You can't put await without async.

Comment: Good catch, I suspect that the whole snippet is wrapped in a function, so this needs to be marked async as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the approach:

```
const sql1 = 'some sql code';
const sql2 = 'Another sql command';

const query1 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    connection.query(sql1, (err, rows, fields) => {
      resolve('something')
    });
  })
};

const query2 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    connection.query(sql2, (err, rows, fields) => {
      resolve('something')
    });
  })
};

[query1, query2].forEach(async request => {
  await request();
});
```